# Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException error

Tags: java

This code worked, but now I'm in trouble.
I think this is the problem, but idk:

```
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
    /C:/Users/alex/workspace/FXMLExample/bin/application/login.fxml:10
```

I don't know / understand what is wrong in these codes. In main just run the scene.
» Main.java

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

public class Main extends Application {

    Parent root;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);

        stage.setTitle("Login system");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

» login.fxml, here I think that is the problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="fxmlexample.Buton"
    alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" styleClass="root">
    <padding>
        <Insets top="25" right="25" bottom="10" left="25" />
    </padding>

    <Text fx:id="bunvenit" text="Bun venit!" GridPane.columnIndex="0"
        GridPane.rowIndex="0" />

    <Text fx:id="text" text="Logheaza-te folosind datele tale personale:"
        GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="2" />

    <Label text="Username:" GridPane.columnIndex="0"
        GridPane.rowIndex="2" />

    <TextField fx:id="username" GridPane.columnIndex="1"
        GridPane.rowIndex="2" />

    <Label text="Parola:" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />

    <PasswordField fx:id="parola" GridPane.columnIndex="1"
        GridPane.rowIndex="3" />

    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="bottom_right" GridPane.columnIndex="1"
        GridPane.rowIndex="5">
        <Button text="Logheaza-te" onAction="#loginButton" />
    </HBox>

    <Text fx:id="eroare" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />

    <Button text="Am uitat parola" GridPane.columnIndex="0"
        GridPane.rowIndex="8" onAction="#passwordButton" />

    <Button text="Creeaza un cont nou" GridPane.columnIndex="1"
        GridPane.rowIndex="8" onAction="#createAccountButton" />

    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@application.css" />
    </stylesheets>

</GridPane>
```

» Buton.java, all buttons actions

```
package fxmlexample;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public abstract class Buton {

    private static final int SCENE_HEIGHT = 600;
    private static final int SCENE_WIDTH = 800;
    @FXML
    private Text eroare;
    @FXML
    private TextField username;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField parola;
    @FXML
    private Parent root;

    /* loginButton */
    @FXML
    protected void loginButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        boolean gasit = false;
        try (BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new    FileReader("data//in//users.txt"))) {
            String linie;
            gasit = false;
            while ((linie = buf.readLine()) != null) {
                String part[] = linie.split(" ");
                if (username.getText().equals(part[0]) && parola.getText().equals(part[1])) {
                    gasit = true;
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (gasit) {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../application/logged.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT);
            Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setTitle("Felicitari, te-ai logat cu succes!");
            stage.show();
        } else {
            eroare.setText("Username sau parola incorecta!");
        }
    }
}
```

» The errors:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/alex/workspace/FXMLExample/bin/application/login.fxml:10

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:15)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    ... 23 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

Comment: I cannot see the following actions from your `FXML` file: `passwordButton` and `createAccountButton` in your controller class. Either remove them from `fxml` or add to the controller class.

Comment: They are there, I accidentally removed them when I pasted the code.

Comment: Are you sure it worked with this `abstract` controller, which does not implement `javafx.fxml.Initializable` interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It clearly says:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException
at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

It just cannot instantiate your abstract `Buton` class. Make it concrete.